# Lucene: fast(er) to get docs in bulk?

Tags: lucene, search-engine, aggregate, bulk

I try to build some real-time aggregates on Lucene as a part of experiment. Documents have their values stored in the index. This works very nice for up-to 10K documents.

For larger numbers of documents, this gets kinda slow. I assume there is not too much invested in getting bulk-amounts of documents, as this kind of defeats the purpose of a search engine.

However, it would be cool to be able to do this. So, basically my question is: what could I do to get documents faster from Lucene? Or are there smarter approaches?

I already only retrieve fields I need.

[edit]
The index is quite large >50GB. This does not fit in memory. The number of fields differ, I have several types of documents. Aggregation will mostly take place on a fixed document type; but there is no way to tell on beforehand which one.

Comment: You're right about the general purpose of the library - retrieving tens of thousands of documents with a lot of fields is not a mainstream use. How many fields do you have? What are your memory constraints? Can you afford putting fields into Field Cache? It could boost performance significantly.

Answer (score 2):

Have you put the index in memory?  If the entire index fits in memory, that is a huge speedup.

Once you get the hits (which comes back super quick even for 10k records), I would open up multiple threads/readers to access them.

Another thing I have done is store only some properties in Lucene (i.e. don't store 50 attributes from a class).  You can get things faster sometimes just by getting a list of IDs and getting the other content from a service/database faster.

Comment: Hi Bart, the index does not fit in memory. I noticed the collection of the docId's is very fast and not a problem. I like the multithreaded reader idea; although it would even be nicer if it could be done faster in a single thread :)

Comment: @RobAu Another thing you can do is split (or Shard) the index up into multiple servers.  This way you are returning 5k instead of 10k (if you have 2 shards).  If you are doing that, Solr might be a better option since Lucene does not have sharding built in.  If you are doing it in Lucene, then you can split the index up and have two web services in front of them and act as the entry point for the Lucene search method.